# Trying to rename an attachment in Access to a field in the table

Tags: database, vba, ms-access, records

Currently I have a table where the 'ID' field is automatically generated through a combination of multiple other fields. Example : ID = '2017_FileName_Chancellor'
Now I've been trying to figure out a way for me to rename this attachment to that ID (by possibly pressing a button in the form)without manually copy pasting the ID and renaming the attached file as that would be tedious when doing it for thousands of records. Is there anyway for me to do this? I have no knowledge in VBA so I could not tamper with that.

Providing a picture of my table might help https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GE0L.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Change the Name of the Attachment in Access:

```
Private Sub Command15_Click()
    Dim NewName As String
    Dim NewNameWithExt As String

    NewName = Me.TestID.Value

    NewNameWithExt = NewName & ".txt"

    DoCmd.RunSQL ("UPDATE TestTable SET TestAttachment.FileName = '" & 
    NewNameWithExt & "' WHERE TestID = " & NewName)

End Sub
```

To Change the Name of the File on the Desktop:

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()
    Dim NewName As String
    Dim OldName As String
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim strSQL As String

    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    strSQL = "SELECT TestAttachment.FileName FROM TestTable WHERE TestID = 1"

    rs.Open strSQL, CurrentProject.Connection, 1, 3

    Do Until rs.EOF
        OldName = rs.Fields(0)
        NewName = CurrentDb.TableDefs("TestTable").Fields(0).Name

        Name "C:\Users\TestUser\desktop\" & OldName As 
        "C:\Users\TestUser\desktop\" & NewName & ".TXT"

        rs.MoveNext
    Loop

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: The file I wish to rename is in the attachement field in the table for each record, like so https://i.imgur.com/mEgr00y.png

Comment: Okay I've updated my response to reflect your last comment.  Note that you'll have to figure out a way to loop through tables if you're pulling from multiple tables.

Comment: I don't need it to do it for all the records/tables, I'd just like to be able to press the button and rename the attachment for the current record I'm on in the form.

Comment: Updated again.  I thought you were trying to update a file outside of Access.

Comment: I changed it a bit because I kept getting a syntax error and it works for when I view the text file through access however the name remains the same when I look at it on my desktop. https://i.imgur.com/1XmgFQI.png

Comment: Haha okay, updated again.... That's originally what I gave you, code to change the name on the desktop.  I've included that and the code for changing the attachment name too.  I would expect some syntax errors since your objects and fields are named differently than mine.  Also for the desktop version, notice that I'm just pulling where TestID = 1.  You'll have to update that so it's pulling the correct ID from the form.  I think I've given you enough here where you should be able to work it out.